# Using npm json-server with Android studio

Tags: java, android, json, okhttp, json-server

I have set a local npm json server using the mentioned tool which will return a very simple get request much like the one shown in the example say:

```
{
  "posts": [
    { "id": 1, "title": "json-server", "author": "typicode" }
  ],
  "comments": [
    { "id": 1, "body": "some comment", "postId": 1 }
  ],
  "profile": { "name": "typicode" }
}
```

All permissions have been set in Android studio regarding internet permissions(which for something this simple it is all I need) and I am using a small okhttp script that makes the asynchronous request to the contents of the url, this is made inside a fragment( thus the use of `getActivity()`)

```
public void testAsyncCreate() {

        OkHttpClient client  = new OkHttpClient();
        // no request body necessary since this is going to be handled via the get request as a testing purpose

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://localhost:3004/create")
                .build();

        Call call = client.newCall(request);

        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

                try {

                    final String jsonData = response.body().string(); // the exception is caught at this point
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Log.d(TAG,jsonData);
                        }
                    });



                }catch(IOException e) {

                }

            }
        });
    }
```

The request is made as soon as the "user" clicks a button. Thus far, my only response from this is:

```
No Network Security Config specified, using patform default
```

Which is quite interesting considering that the same request using a NON local server (for example get request made to the poke api) returns the body of the json content as intended)

At this point I am sure that it was to do with the fact that it is a local environment. And thus far I can't find specific documentation with details regarding testing on local environments. Debugging returns tag=null as soon as the `call.enqueue()` portion begins as well.

Comment: aw man I'm going to get another tumbleweed...

Comment: Have you been able to make requests to the server using a browser or PostMan?

Comment: Oh, wait.  Is this server on the phone?  localhost will only go to servers on the phone which is more difficult.  You need to link to the network IP.

Comment: @DeeV indeed, It works on both postman as well as on the browser. Heck, it even works with a Python script I made to test it out.

Comment: On an Android Emulator, you should be able to link to running servers on your computer if you go to `10.0.2.2` instead of `localhost`.  Otherwise, if you're on a phone, you need to point it to the IP address in your local network, and it needs to be on the same wifi as your computer, and you need to remove whatever firewall may be blocking you.

Comment: Made te change to 10.0.2.2 and now it is `http://10.0.2.2/create` but I am still not able to connect(gives a 404 now). I am working with the emulator at the moment. It is still not working but I learned something new. Thanks DeeV let's see if any other suggestions arise

Comment: You need the port too.

Comment: ah! that was silly. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can bypass all you localhost call using a [Http Toolkit](https://httptoolkit.com/) without doing any changes. It will help you to bypass all your localhost calls to your device or emulator.

Comment: Here check this, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DRrMefq-cuk